# Solving the problem via MVT.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, mean-value-theorem

Here is the problem I am trying to solve:

> Suppose $f : [1, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable with continuous derivative and 
>  (a) $f(1) = 1$ 
>  (b) $x f'(x) \leq \frac{1}{2} f(x)$ 
>  Show that $f(x) \leq x^{1/2}$ for all $x \geq 1$.

---

**My trial**

I assumed that $f(x) = x^m$ (which satisfies the first assumption) and I used the second assumption together with the derivative of the defined $f(x)$ above to conclude that $m = \frac12$. But I am wondering if we can solve the problem via MVT? Could someone help me in answering this question please?

Comment: why are you allowed to assume that though?

Comment: I meant I took this function and it satisfied the first assumption @JustWandering

Comment: @Emptymind: You can't do that! You're supposed to prove it for _every_ such $f$, not just functions of your choosing.

Comment: Hint: consider the function $g(x)=x^{-1/2}f(x)$. What do you get if you differentiate it?

Comment: Ok, I see for your first comment and for your second comment unfortunately it is answered below :( @TonyK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(\frac {f(x)} {\sqrt x})'=\frac {\sqrt x f'(x)-\frac 1 2 f(x)x^{-1/2}} {x} \leq 0$ so $\frac {f(x)} {\sqrt x}$ is decreasing. Hence $\frac {f(x)} {\sqrt x} \leq \frac {f(1)} 1=1$. You can apply MVT to $\frac {f(x)} {\sqrt x}-\frac {f(1)} 1$ if you wish, but that looks unnecessary.